# How to remove a notification when clicked, or service is finished?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

How to remove notification from screen when it is clicked? Or if it is a service, and the service has finished its onCreate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cancel the notification:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int)

Comment: How would you refer to it by int id?

Comment: when you show the notification, you pass in an id (`notify(int id, Notification notification)`) ... use that same id ;-)